# Simple search function for a list of products - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, web-applications

I'm currently self-studing Ruby on Rails 3 out of wanting to code my own apps and designs (total noob). I'm writing up code for a simple product list and I want to integrate a simple search function in order to search items by item_name and / or item_code. I am getting this error:

NameError in ItemsController#index

undefined local variable or method `params' for #

here is my code:

Model

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :description, :item_code, :item_name

      validates_uniqueness_of :item_code, :item_name

      validates :item_name, :item_code, :presence => true

      def self.search(query)
        if query
          find(:all, :conditions => ['item_name LIKE ?', "% #{params[query]} %"] )
        else
          find(:all)
        end
      end

   end
```

View:

```
    <%= form_tag items_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :placeholder => "Search items here" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>

    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
    def index
      @items = Item.search(params[:search])
    end
```

I was following this particular screencast, don't know what I did wrong: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `params[query]` in your `self.search` method, try just `query` there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Item.search(params[:search])` gives the function `search` an argument which is the `params[:search]`.

the argument named in `search` method is `query`, so in your `search` method, `query` just stand for `params[:search]`. and there is no `params` argument which ruby complain to you.